# hide td element depending on class from th

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been searching the forums for a bit but couldn't find a solution to my picky question.

I have a table I'm building programmatically. First building the `<thead>` element, some `<th>` elements will have a certain class. Then building the `<tbody>`, I want the `<td>` elements that fall under the `<th>` column with the certain class, to hide. (Ofcourse I will hide the `<th>` with the class also).

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: have you tried this by your own?

Comment: I have no idea where to start.. was thinking of making an array with indexes from the `<th>` elements with the class, then somehow using css to use `td:nth-child(index)` to display:none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, what about something like this ?

```
var nth_column=0;
var th_with_class=[]; /* columns whose th has a certain class */
```

get `<th>` with a certain class  :

```
jQuery("th").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("foo")) {
        th_with_class.push(nth_column);
    }
    nth_column++;
});
```

And then, hide `<th>` and `<tds>` :

```
for (i; i<th_with_class.length; i++) {
    nth_column=th_with_class[i];
    $("tr > *:nth-child("+nth_column+")").addClass("hidden");
}
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need, let me try it out

Comment: close. 2 issues: the `nth_column++` needs to occur after the `if ($(this).hasClass("foo")) {` block. and it only takes the nth `<td>` of the first row

Comment: if you add a `row_count = 1` and in the for loop, make `nth_column_row = nth_column * row_count;`, after the for loop `row_count++` it works. if you edit your answer with this I will accept it ^^

Comment: You're right with `nth_column++` so I moved it.
But why do you need to use `nth_column_row` ?
I just realized my answer do not permit to hide the <th>. It can be done with `$("tr > *")` instead of `$("td")`

Comment: I need `nth_column_row` because your answer only works for the first row (i.e. first row is td#28, next row would be td#56, etc)

Comment: You're right ! I suggest using `$("tr > *:nth-child("+nth_column")")` which is a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a table template with `display:none` property.

```
<table id="tempTable" style="display:none">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="hideClass"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="hideClass"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="hideClass firstTd"></td>
            <td class="secondTd"></td>
            <td class="hideClass"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="tableContainer">

</div>
```

After that clone this table with `.clone()` . Remove `Id` and `display:none` from element. Add your data to specific location on table and append the table to a div.

```
var tableElem = $('#tempTable').clone();
tableElem.attr('id', '');
tableElem.css('display', 'block');

//Add your data to specific element like;
tableElem.find('tbody .firstTd').text('Your text');

//After adding data to table append it to div or wherever you want
$('#tableContainer').append(tableElem);
```

This is the best way to create table. It is simple and you know what you are creating because there is a template.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding the 3rd column, you can add a `.hidden` class to `th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3)`

In your css you would have

```
.hidden{
    display : none;
}
```

Comment: ok but I dunno which column I need to hide, I dunno if it's 3rd or 9th, that depends on the th with the class

Comment: You're making the table programmatically so you can create a list `var indexes = []` then `indexes.push(i)` when you add a th with the hide class. You can then add the hidden class using jquery and the selector built from the values in your list